# Bibtex and \cref in Auxilary directory

Tags: bibtex

Created an auxfiles directory for the Latex auxiliary files.
[image: TeXstudio configurations]

Yet when I pdflatex, not only \cref is not referencing but bibtex failed with the following

```
    Process started: bibtex.exe "Report"  -output_directory=./auxfiles
    bibtex.exe
    : Invalid command-line option bibtex.exe: Data: unknown option
```

Comment: Which front-end editing software do you use?

Comment: Does bibtex even support output directory? The option looks a bit suspicious, perhaps `-output-directory` is correct (though, I have never understood why people use this)

Answer (score 1):

pdflatex:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex -aux-directory=./temp
```

Bibtex should have exactly the following command

```
bibtex.exe ./temp/%
```

and the build should also search in `./temp/`